# NODE JS with building model & Inserting data to database

Tags: node.js

I am a beginner with NODEJS & JS.
I want to build a User model which is used to make register page.
There's no error in nodejs console, but the new data always doesn't insert to my DB.
I use MYSQL, and don't want to use Mongoose to build models(MongoDB).
I think there's something wrong in [User.prototype.save = function save(callback)]
and I'm sure that connecting to DB is fine.
How can I revise?

//model.js

```
//model.js
var mysql = require("mysql");
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '123456',
    database:'test'
});
function User(user) {
    this.username = user.username;
    this.userpass = user.userpass;
};
module.exports = User;
User.prototype.save = function save(callback) {
    var user = {
        username: this.username,
        userpass: this.userpass
    };
    var cmd = "INSERT INTO member(Account_id, Account_password) VALUES(?,?)";
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query(cmd, [user.username, user.userpass], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("GG");
            } else {
                console.log("Yes");
            }
        });
        connection.release();
        callback(err, result);
    });  
};
```

//test.js

```
//test.js
var User = require('./model.js');
var newUser = new User({
    username: 'yesggdd123',
    userpass: '123456789'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in the code after `pool.getConnection` :

```
   pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query(cmd, [user.username, user.userpass], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("GG");
            } else {
                console.log("Yes");
            }
        });
        connection.release(); //<--- These will execute immediately 
        callback(err, result);//<--- after getConnection calls back
   });
```

You need to move the `release` and `callback` up inside the callback from `connection.query`, so that things happen in the right order

```
   pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query(cmd, [user.username, user.userpass], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("GG");
            } else {
                console.log("Yes");
            }
            connection.release(); //<-- Now these happen after query calls back
            callback(err, result);//<--
        });
   });
```

Comment: I changed, but it still can not insert to my DB

Comment: What are the contents of `err` and `result` from the query callback?